# Industry standard for organizing dev work

Tags: organization

I am a CIS student and want to do the best industry standard for organizing projects. I find my desktop and dev folder cluttered with different projects and would like some advice on how to better organize like a professional. Thanks

Comment: use source control for EVERYTHING and make sure you push to a remote repo

Comment: Well, here's how I do it. My dev folder is all cluttered with old projects, my desktop is a horrid mess, and my desktop is a horrid mess (the real one). I'm pretty sure the person who sits next to me does the same, except he is collecting old fast food cups too. Seems pretty "standard" to me.

Comment: "no standard" is the only standard

Comment: question is very subjective and very broad - what is professional behaviour? This site deals with questions and answers around software engineering. You can probably pick a self-help book from a bookstore on how to get organized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So there *is* a standard. But you are missing the point a bit with the worry about your own computer and files/folders etc

If you want to develop professionally there are just a couple of things you should do.

1. Source control.

   You really have to have everything in source control. Use Git and make sure you push to a repository on a different box. the cloud is fine, bitlocker or github etc
2. Build server

   You have to have a build server, push you code and have an automated script compile it, and another automated script to deploy it to live if possible.
3. Tests

   Write unit tests, integration tests, end to end tests etc etc. Run them as part of your build if possible.
4. To do List of Tasks

   Again you will want a tool, something like trello to keep track of what you are wanting to achieve and have completed to far.

If you do these things, you can wipe your development PC and you still have everything backed up. You know when you have broken something and when a feature is completed, and most of all. You can get someone to help you with your work and they can make meaningful contributions easily.

If you can expand from one person, to two and then to a team, then you know you are doing things well. It doesn't matter how cluttered your PC is.